# Are the following data type allocations analagous?

Tags: c#, objective-c, vb.net, types

I'm very interested in languages and their underpinnings, and I'd like to pose this question to the community. Are the following analagous to eachother in these languages?

C#

```
Foo bar = default(Foo); //alloc
bar = new Foo(); //init
```

VB.NET

```
Dim bar As Foo = Nothing  'alloc
bar = New Foo()   'init
```

Objective-C

```
Foo* bar = [Foo alloc];   //alloc
bar = [bar init];    //init
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type Foo can either be a Value Type or a Reference Type, except in Objective-C of course.

Assuming Foo is a reference type, then for C# and VB.NET the first line will not allocate any memory for the object were as the Objective-C first line will actually allocate the memory, so this is a difference. The .NET languages perform the allocation and initialization in one line in the second line.

In the case that Foo is a Value Type, then the .NET languages are analagous to each other, Objective-C does not have value types (at least not the last time I worked with it 15 years ago).

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting `bar` in both C# and VB.NET. Your code is equivalent to just:

```
Foo bar;  // does nothing but declare a handle
bar = new Foo(); // alloc AND init
```

or simply:

```
Foo bar=new Foo();
```

Where Obj-C apparently separates allocation from initialization, all other C++-like languages combine the 2, thinking (correctly imo) that you never want to have partially-uninitialized objects (constructors aside, of course).